# Get last updated records Doctrine Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, doctrine-orm

I need to edit data that exists in a table. Upon editing , i want to keep a copy of the old data. So instead of using an `update` statement , i am using an `insert` to insert the new updated data on to the same table. Both sets of data have a certain `id` that is the same, it helps me keep track of the changes. The table also has an `autoincrement` field.Something like below:

```
> id Data            Data_id
> 1. Data1                01
> 2. Data1_edit1          01
> 3. Data2                02
> 4. Data2_edit1          02
```

id is `autoincrement` , Data_id helps keep log of the changes.
The table is also `timestampable`. Such that Data1 will have a lower timestamp than Data1_edit1.

Say I want to get the latest updated records of `Data2` i.e `id` `4` & `Data1` i.e `id` `2` , I am trying to do this using:

```
-> select("*") 
-> from("data")
-> groupBy("Data_id")
```

As is expected this returns `Data1` & `Data2`, how would I be able to return `Data1_edit1` and `Data2_edit1`?

Am using `Doctrine 2` and `Mysql`

Help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from yourtable
where id in(select max(id) from yourtable group by data_id)
```

Its working properly.
SQL FIDDLE

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e04c/1)

Comment: Thanks man, it does. My bad. had put the `group by ` outside the `in()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
select * from data where (data_id, id ) in ( select data_id, max(id) from data group by Data_id );
```